# How to insert multiple row from form in laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

I have a table in a form similar to this:

| products | comments |
| --- | --- |
| product 1 | comment 1 |
| product 2 | comment 2 |

- Only comment field is writable where user can enter a comment regarding each product
- Products are displayed from database (not in an input element)

I want, when user click on save button, each row is added in database as it is in the form (as pairs [product i, comment i])

I tried

```
foreach ($request->products as $key=>$product) {
            $saveData = [
                'product' => $request->product[$key],
                'comment' => $request->comment[$key],
            ];
            DB::table('prod_com')->insert($saveData);
        }
```

in controller and

```
<form id="regForm" method="post" >
 @csrf
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Comment</th>
  </tr>
  @foreach($prdcts as $products)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$products['product']}}</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment[]" >
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

in form but either data isn't added in database or i get a 405 error Method Not Allowed..

Any help is highly appreciated !

**Edit :**
Full html form

```
<form id="regForm" action="{{route('saved')}}" method="post" >
       @csrf    
       <table class="table table-responsive table-condebsed table-hover">
           <thead>
             <tr>
              <th scop="col"> Product </th>
              <th class="col-md-6" scop="col"> Comment </th>
             </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              @foreach($prdcts as $products)
              <tr>
               <td>{{ $products['product'] }}</td>
               <td>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment[]" >
               </td>
              </tr>
             @endforeach
            </tbody>
           </table>
           <br>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">save</button>
</form>
```

& route :

```
Route::post('/saved', [App\Http\Controllers\ProdComController::class, 'submitData'])->name('saved');
```

Comment: can you show full html form code  and route for that

Comment: Just updated with full html form and route code, I want to know how can I get (each) product value from table as it is not in an input element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change html code as below

```
 @foreach($prdcts as $key=>$products)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$products['product']}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="product[{{ $key}}][product]" value="{{$products['id']}}">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product[{{ $key}}][comment]" >
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
```

then in controller

```
 DB::table('prod_com')->insert($request->product);
```

if you get any error then try to print $request like below

```
dd($request->all());
```

so you can check data format in the request.If still issue then let me know in the comment

Comment: I just added the hidden input before comment's input and it worked as wanted. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

you can use for loop while saving your data into database

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->comment); $i++) {
       $comment = Commet::create([
            
            'comment' => $request->comment[$i],
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you ! Also I changed $key=>$product to $key=>$insert in my controller code and it worked too..